# Correct way to use optional parameter in Java Azure Function

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to figure out how to create Azure Functions using Java with a simple temperature conversion function.  The route I've tried to define is:

temps/{method}/{temp?}

I've modified the templated HttpTrigger code generated for a new Java project with:

```
   @FunctionName("temps")
   public HttpResponseMessage run(
        @HttpTrigger(name = "req", 
                    methods = {HttpMethod.GET}, 
                    authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS,
                    route = "temps/{method}/{temp:float?}") 
            HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            @BindingName("method") String method,
            @BindingName("temp") String temp,
            final ExecutionContext context) {...}
```

It works fine when I actually pass a temperature value as the last parameter, but if I just call "temps/{method}", I get a **NullPointerException** at

```
com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.binding.BindingDataStore.getTriggerMetatDataByName(BindingDataStore.java:54).
```

So I'm assuming that I'm not correctly defining the bindings so that it can properly handle when the last parameter is not included in the URI.  I've seen a number of other posts about this which indicate including the '?' should work, so wondering if I'm missing something obvious.  Note: I've got code to test whether the value passed in temp is a value float, so that's working OK.

Answer (score 0):

I found another post which included an example of providing a default value if an optional parameter is not included:

```
    @FunctionName("temps")
    public HttpResponseMessage run(
        @HttpTrigger(name = "req", 
                    methods = {HttpMethod.GET}, 
                    authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS,
                    route = "temps/{method}/{temp=NONE}") 
            HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            @BindingName("method") String method,
            @BindingName("temp") String temp,
            final ExecutionContext context) {...}
```

This seems to work, but it doesn't explain why other posted examples with '?' to designate an optional parameter don't (unless it just doesn't work in Java but does in C#).  I also found that when providing a default value, you cannot seem to also include the parameter type, e.g. "{temp**:float**=NONE}".

Answer (score 0):

I think there are multiple problems with route parameters in Java. 
I actually created an issue in the GitHub repository for Azure functions in Java about this problem that I had to deal with too, don't hesitate to add more details that you could have so maybe it will get more attention: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/issues/293.

Edit:

Here's another possible workaround, that works with parameter types (in fact, this solution only works if they're specified): write the parameters with a question mark, but **do not** retrieve them with the `@BindingName` annotation. Instead, parse the URL directly in the function.

So for example:

```java
@FunctionName("example")
public HttpResponseMessage exampleFunction (
    @HttpTrigger(
        name = "functionTrigger",
        authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS,
        methods = {HttpMethod.GET},
        route = "example/{param1:int?}/{param2:int?}" // specify the parameters like this
    ) final HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
    final ExecutionContext context
) {
    String[] parameters = request.getUri().getPath().split("/"); // though types were specified, with this way of doing you retrieve the parameters as strings
    int param1 = 0;
    int param2 = 0;
    if (parameters.length > 3) {
        param1 = Integer.parseInt(parameters[3]);
        if (parameters.length > 4) {
            param2 = Integer.parseInt(parameters[4]);
        }
    }
    return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK)
        .body("You sent " + param1 + " and " + param2)
        .build();
}
```

A precision: though you retrieve the parameters as strings, the fact that you specified the types in the route path prevents users from sending values of different types (if they try to do so, the function will automatically respond with a 404 Not Found).

Also, and this is what makes this workaround a far from ideal solution, you have to be careful with the number of "/" in the URL path (e.g. don't forget the "api" prefix that comes just after the domain if you haven't removed it, etc.).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.